# Save the state of a Circleimageview inside a fragment

Tags: android, imageview, onresume, onsaveinstancestate

I have fragments with a circleimageview inside used as a profile image that is saved later in a database correctly. 
My problem is to save the state of the imageview with onSaveInstanceState and onPause/onStop to keep their state before saving them in the database and after, for example, performing a screen rotation.
This is my code

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private CircleImageView mPhoto;
    private byte[] bytes = null;
    private Bitmap photo = null;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if(bytes!=null) {
            outState.putByteArray("bytes", bytes);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        view =  lf.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment,container,false);
        mPhoto = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        view.findViewById(R.id.photo).setOnClickListener(this);

        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("bytes")){
                bytes = savedInstanceState.getByteArray("bytes");
                if(bytes != null) {
                    //but with a screen rotation the image is not restored
                    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    mPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }
            }
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.photo:
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), 0);
                }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri path = data.getData();
            Bitmap tmp = null;
            try {
                tmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(tmp != null) {
                mPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
                bytes = getBitmapAsByteArray(photo);
                //tested, bytes is not null and the photo are restored correctly when saved on the database 
            }

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bytes = getActivity().getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("bytes");
        if(bytes != null) {
            //here bytes is null
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            mPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(bytes!=null)
            getActivity().getIntent().putExtra("bytes",bytes);
    }
}
```

in this way the image is not maintained during a screen rotation, how to correctly implement onsavedInstanceState, onStop and onResume?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way Use ViewModel with your fragment.

Refer: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html

**Update**:

Step1: Add [View Model dependency](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies) in build.gradle

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
```

Step 2: Create a ViewModel for Fragment

```
public class MyFragmentViewModel extends ViewModel {
}
```

Step 3: Set ViewModel in MyFragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
 public void onStart() {
     MyFragmentViewModel userModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyFragmentViewModel.class);
 }
}
```

Comment: @james I have updated the answer with steps to follow. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Put code before super() method.

```
 @Override
public void onStop() {
    if(bytes!=null)
    getActivity().getIntent().putExtra("bytes",bytes);
    super.onStop();

}
```